# Two html on android page

Tags: android, google-visualization, android-studio

I m using google visualization and i was wondering if there is a way to show 2 charts (1 column chart and the other one Donut chart) on the same page.

Thanks in advance.

Fabricio

PS : i m using android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can show two charts on one page.  Here's some basic code to get you started:

```
function drawCharts () {
    var columnData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    // populate with data

    var pieData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    // populate with data

    var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.querySelector('#column_chart_div'));
    columnChart.draw(columnData, {/* options */});

    var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.querySelector('#pie_chart_div'));
    pieChart.draw(pieData, {/* options */});
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawCharts});
```

You'll need two divs in the HTML:

```
<div id="column_chart_div"></div>
<div id="pie_chart_div"></div>
```

If the charts draw data from the same source, you can use the same DataTable for both, they don't have to be different.